# Tree Rewrite - whole subtree not just the top node should become root

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I want that the tree rewrite of *addition_operator* contains the whole subtree not only the top node, so that *hint_keywords* are still in the tree.

*addition* is so complex because I want to add the T_LEFT and T_RIGHT in the tree.

antlr 3.3

grammar:

```
grammar Test;

options {
    output = AST;
}

tokens {
    T_LEFT;
    T_RIGHT;
    T_MARKER;
}

@lexer::header {
    package com.spielwiese;
}

@header {
    package com.spielwiese;
}

NUM         :   '0' .. '9' ( '0' .. '9' )*;
ASTERISK    :   '*';
PLUS        :   '+';
MINUS       :   '-';
WS  :   (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n') {skip();};

addition
    :
        (a=atom -> $a)
        (
            addition_operator b=atom
            ->
                ^(addition_operator
                    ^(T_LEFT  $addition)
                    ^(T_RIGHT $b)
                )
        )+
    ;

atom
    :   NUM
    |   '(' addition ')' -> addition
    ;

addition_operator
    :   PLUS  hints? -> ^(PLUS  hints?)
    |   MINUS hints? -> ^(MINUS hints?)
    ;

hints
    : '[' hint_keywords += hint_keyword (',' hint_keywords += hint_keyword)* ']'
        ->
            $hint_keywords
    ;

hint_keyword
    :   'FAST'
    |   'SLOW'

    |   'BIG'
    |   'THIN'
    ;
```

As far as I can see the reason is the implementation of RewriteRuleSubtreeStream#nextNode() which uses adaptor.dupNode(tree) and I want a adaptor.dupTree(tree).

given input

2 + [BIG] 3 - [FAST, THIN] 4

is:

```
              +---------+
              |    -    |
              +---------+
                   |    \
                   |     \
                T_LEFT  T_RIGHT
                   |       |
              +---------+
              |    +    |  4
              +---------+
                   |   \     
                 T_LEFT  T_RIGHT
                   |       |
                   2       3
```

and should be

```
              +---------+
              |    -    |
              +---------+
            /  /    |    \
           /  /     |     \
      FAST THIN  T_LEFT  T_RIGHT
                    |       |
               +---------+
               |    +    |  4
               +---------+
               /   |   \     
              /   T_LEFT  T_RIGHT
            BIG    |       |
                   2       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grammar Test;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  T_MARKER;
  T_LEFT;
  T_RIGHT;
}

calc
 : addition EOF -> addition
 ;

addition
 : (a=atom -> $a) ( Add markers b=atom -> ^(Add markers ^(T_LEFT $addition) ^(T_RIGHT $b))
                  | Sub markers b=atom -> ^(Sub markers ^(T_LEFT $addition) ^(T_RIGHT $b))
                  )*
 ;

markers
 : ('[' marker (',' marker)* ']')? -> ^(T_MARKER marker*)
 ;

marker
 : Fast
 | Thin
 | Big
 ;

atom
 : Num
 | '(' addition ')' -> addition
 ;

Fast  : 'FAST';
Thin  : 'THIN';
Big   : 'BIG';
Num   : '0'..'9' ('0'..'9')*;
Add   : '+';
Sub   : '-';
Space : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {skip();};
```

which parses the input `2 + [BIG] 3 - [FAST, THIN] 4 + 5` into the following AST:

[image]

The trick was to use `$addition` in the rewrite rule to reference the entire rule itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! It solves the problem very well! But T_MARKER is only an example for more complex subtree. In your solution you are setting T_MARKER explicit. I need a generic solution for the subtree.